# jquery replacewith function: cannot replace with <form>

Tags: jquery, forms, replacewith

When I click on #demo_3, it simply eliminates the button. However, if inside the `replaceWith()` I put a `<p> O, hai! </p>`, O, hai! will appear.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#demo_3").click(function(){
    $("#ind_3").replaceWith('<form action="newgoal.php" method="post"><input name="newgoal" type="text"></form>');

  });
});
```

Comment: Don't know why you are doing it this way but seems to work fine http://jsfiddle.net/t2uxZ/

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure what your question is, but if you are suggesting that the code you've posted won't replace `#ind_3` I would say are wrong and your issue is somewhere else.  You can see it functioning here:

http://jsfiddle.net/9rnRa/

Just to clarify: My answer is that you CAN replace `#ind_3` with the HTML you are trying and if it's not working for you then you have another issue.

Comment: Thanks, I do have an issue somewhere else.